# gcc vs MSVC C++: pushing a queue of unique_ptrs into a vector

Tags: c++, visual-c++, g++, clang++

It's a well known fact that if you want to push something into `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Foo>>`, then you have to move ownership of that pointer to Foo to the vector:

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Foo>> vector;
std::unique_ptr<Foo> item;

vector.push_back(item); // Fails, as copy constructor is deleted for unique ptr
vector.push_back(std::move(item)); // Works
```

Pushing to a vector-of-vectors-of-unique-pointers also works this way:

```
std::vector<std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Foo>>> vector;
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Foo>> item;

vector.push_back(item); // Fails
vector.push_back(std::move(item)); // Works
```

Things get complicated when instead of vector-of-unique-pointers, I try to use the same technique on queue-of-unique-pointers:

```
std::vector<std::queue<std::unique_ptr<Foo>>> vector;
std::queue<std::unique_ptr<Foo>> item;

vector.push_back(std::move(item));
```

This actually compiles and works perfectly on MSVC 2015, but on gcc 5.4.0, gcc 7.3.0, or clang 3.8.0 with both `-std=c++11` and `-std=c++17` it also fails due to deleted unique_ptr constructor.

Why is this difference, and what is the correct, cross-platform way to push a queue-of-unique-ptrs into a vector, moving ownership?

**UPDATE**: Found a workaround that forces queue to be backed by vector, this compiles & works properly on both gcc and MSVC:

```
typedef std::queue<std::unique_ptr<Foo>, std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Foo>>> Item;
std::vector<Item> vector;
Item item;
vector.push_back(std::move(item));
```

But deque is still problematic :(

Comment: `std::emplace_back` is your friend.

Comment: @JesperJuhl If you mean vector's `emplace_back`, then `vector.emplace_back(std::move(item))` still fails to compile with gcc/clang.

Comment: I meant `vector.emplace_back(Item());` or `vector.emplace_back({});`

Comment: The problem is not with moving `item` into vector, but with moving existing elements around in case the vector needs to reallocate. This can use move constructor of the elements only if it's marked `noexcept`, otherwise it must copy elements and then destroy originals once the copy succeeds - this is necessary to meet exception safety guarantees mandated by the standard. It so happens that `std::vector`'s move constructor is `noexcept`, while `std::deque`'s one is not (for reasons unclear); or at least, the standard doesn't require it to be so marked.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik The answer box is below ;)

Comment: @IgorTandetnik So, in other words, there is no way to do it in standard C++?

Comment: Yes, it does appear that `std::vector<std::deque<MoveOnlyType>>` is essentially unusable in a portable manner.